# Regex match between two chars with chars greater than 1

Tags: regex

Here is my text:
`378-Columbian Forecast Yr-NB-Q-Columbian_NB`

I need to find `Columbian Forecast Yr` or whatever it happens to be.

My current regex is: `\-(.*)\-`. This returns:`-Columbian Forecast Yr-` and `-Q-`

I only want the first to be returned.

How can I have my regular expression search for a string between - and - with the number of chars being greater than 1? - and possibly as well to not return the hyphens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
-([^-]+.)-
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/eJ6gO8/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^[^-]*-([^-]{2,})-
```

and grab captured group #1

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vP7bV2/1)

Comment: why need `^[^-]*`? i think just `-([^-]{2,})-` and group 1 should be good.

Comment: Yes it should have been good too but I don't know which regex flavor is being used here. And without `^[^-]*` rest of the regex might give multiple matches also.